# What is the std::filesystem counterpart of stat.st_rdev for block devices and character devices?

Tags: c++, unix, c++17, posix, std

The `std::filesystem` library provides nice portable bindings for directory tree traversal and all kinds of filetypes and almost all the features I know of a typical UNIX/POSIX system are there (hardlink count etc.).

Problem: I fail to find the `stat.st_rdev` information in `std::filesystem::status`. I know that the `st_rdev` field is highly OS dependent and even filesystem specific. It contains the major/minor numbers of block and character devices on UNIX-like systems (Linux, macOS etc).

Question: Do I have to revert to using the C APIs for these (`stat()` for reading and `mknod()` for creating) or am I overlooking something in `std::filesystem`?

Comment: I'm guessing that since Windows doesn't implement an equivalent, then it's missing. Checking the Boost FS library (on which std::fs is based), I can't find any references to `st_rdev`.

Comment: I just realized that `st_dev` and `st_ino` are also not accessible through. `std::filesystem::status'. These are necessary to build tables of hardlinked files. Of course the use of these fields is exotic, but it would be useful to have access to them on system which support them.