C++ std::filesystem equivalent of st_blksize from the C stat function?
Is there a C++ std::filesystem equivalent of the C stat() function declared in #include <sys/stat.h> to get info about the st_blksize attribute?

AFAIK no, filesystem is not designed to access lower level hardware information. And to me that makes sense a device may have a file system and not even have something akin to a blocksize (it is a hardware detail). You can find all filesystem features here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74932537/what-is-the-stdfilesystem-counterpart-of-stat-st-rdev-for-block-devices-and-ch

not all files are on a block device. And the C++ standard doesn't know about devices either

There is no equivalent of st_blksize in the std::filesystem library.
